# Need advice on approximating the sum of a trigonomitric series which (I think) has no analytical solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

I've encountered a maths problem in a programming project I'm working on. I've tried a lot of things already, and I'm feeling very swamped with maths that is way above my head.

I need to find:

$$f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N cos(n^2x)$$

Now I've discovered I can use de Moivre's theorum and express this as the real part of an exponential series

$$Re\{ \sum_{n=1}^N e^{in^2x} \}$$

After some investigation I don't believe there is an analytical solution for this, so I'm not sure it's useful.

Numerical appromimations are better than the brute force approach I'm currently using as speed is far more importent than accuracy for my use case.

I believe what I'm looking for is the Taylor expansion of the first equation - however I have no idea how to approach finding the Taylor expansion of a sum to n. Maybe it's not possible? Googleing hasn't helped me here, searching "Taylor expansion of a finite series" just comes up with results for "Taylor series".

I think that maybe what I can do is find the derivatives of $f_N(x)$ use those as the terms in the Taylor series. I have a few questions:

- Am I correct in saying that the second equation doesn't have an analytical solution?
- Is using the Taylor expansion by finding the derivatives of the series the correct approach? (UPDATE: Just found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864635/taylor-expansion-for-formal-power-series), which is for a polynomial rather than a trigonometric function, but leads me to believe that this method is valid. UPDATE 2: not possible, coefficients in the taylor expansion are themselves a series)
- If so, does anyone have any examples of a Taylor expansion of a series that I could look at?
- If not, what alternatives should I be looking at for finding a numerical approximation?

UPDATE: I should add that x is small, $0 < n^2x < \pi$ which should make
approximations easier

Thanks!

PS: I'm not a mathematician (which I'm sure is obvious!) and it has been a long time since I was at uni - would really appreciate answers in the form a comp-sci undergraduate could understand (to the extent to which that is possible!)

Comment: Have you consider approximating this via an integral instead. Look up [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: I will have a look at that, thanks!

Comment: $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n cos(n^2 x)=n\,cos(n^2 x)$. I assume you mean $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n cos(i^2 x)$ or $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n cos(i n^2 x)$?

Comment: Yes! Edited it now.

Comment: You overloaded $n$. Perhaps $f_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N cos(n^2 x)$?

Comment: Sorry. Better now?

Comment: What you have is a very sparse trigonometric polynomial. The limit for $N\to\infty$ is a very non-smooth function. So it is doubtful that you find a better approximation than the original expression. This is similar to transcendental numbers of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 10^{-n^2}$ where the best rational approximations are the partial sums.

Comment: @LutzLehmann $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{i n^2 x}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{i x}-1\right)\right)$, so is it really analogous to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 10^{-n^2}$?

Comment: This is expressible through elliptic functions. So maybe you can try to check out some methods to numerically compute elliptic functions instead.

Comment: @StevenClark : Both use the same "fragment" of the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}$, in that sense they are similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I think the answer is probably yes after finding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864635/taylor-expansion-for-formal-power-series), but can anyone confirm for me if I can take the Taylor expansion of the trigonometric series? My use case doesn't require perfect accuracy and storing a large number of expansion coefficients in memory isn't a problem in any case

Comment: Never mind, I see now why the Taylor expansion of the trigonometric series is not possible

Comment: Do you mean $0 < n^2x < \pi$ or $0 < N^2x < \pi$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n^2x)= \text{Re}\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i x n^2}  $$

Now a difference:

$$\sum_{n=0}^b a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=b}^\infty a_n\implies  \text{Re}\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i x n^2} =  \text{Re}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i x n^2} - \text{Re}\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{i x n^2} $$

So the general idea is to:

$$\text{Re}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i x n^2} - \text{Re}\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{i x n^2}= \text{Re}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i x n^2} - \text{Re}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{i x (n+N)^2} $$

Now use [Jacobi theta functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)

However, an infinite sum, by itself, [may diverge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+cos%28n%5E2%2F3%29+from+n%3D1+to+infty+)

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Thanks for this - might take me a while to make sense of those Jacobi theta functions!

Comment: @Newt I do not know much about them either, but they still are useful for similar problems.

Comment: I'm wondering if a closed form is really useful. Is there a more efficient way to approximate an elliptic theta function which is an infinite series rather than just evaluating the original sum which is a finite series?

Comment: @StevenClark Your can explore [this Wolfram Elliptic functions link](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/) to find identities

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think this goes far beyond my maths skills. Thanks for the help, I'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Please post an answer with some insights since fresnel integrals will be interesting to use. The [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula) may or may not apply.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I meant the Jacobi theta functions - I'm looking at Fresnel integrals! The wikipedia page on them has a lot of links to papers on approximating them, which is exactly what I needed